# Require module in Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I used Node JS for web application development. I have a confusion in `require()` module. I am requiring a JS file located in file_handler directory.
What is the difference between both of the following?

// in server.js

```
var chat = require("./file_handler/chat.js");    // Does not work
```

OR

```
var chat = require("./file_handler/chat.js")(); // It works
```

Why is the extra parenthesis in the last of the statement?

Comment: Parenthesis execute a function. You can work out the rest from that information.

Comment: Thanx.. i got it.

Answer (score 0):

In the first line the exported function is assigned to chat variable so then you can call it like next like `chat();`

In the second one the return of exported function is returned to chat variable.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually based on what you `export` in your module. If you export the object you need, you can just directly do `require('module')`. If you export a function which returns the object you need, you have to execute that exported function `require('module')()` to get the desired object.

Read the documentation https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html